# Find Particular String in File and Count How many Times it is repeated using perl

Tags: perl

I have a Long File Say 10000 Lines.

That is same set of Data Repeated , Like 10 lines and next ten line will be Same.

I want to Find Say "ObjectName" String in that file and Count it, How Many Times is appearing in that file.

Can anyone post detailed code. I am new to Perl.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  Hint: asking for someone to post detailed code sounds like you're too lazy to do the work yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

```
perl -ne '$x+=s/objname//g;END{print $x,"\n";}' file
```

**Updated**:
  Since OP wants the solution using handlers:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;    

open my $fh , '<' , 'f.txt' or die 'Cannot open file';

my $x=0;
while (<$fh>){
        chomp;
        $x+=s/objname//g;
}

close $fh;

print "$x";
```

Comment: Is that Can be written as Program with handlers

Comment: Thanks it works fine..How to pass multiple files and have to same search in whole directory

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option that also addresses your comment about searching in a whole directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir   = '.';
my $count = 0;
my $find  = 'ObjectName';

for my $file (<$dir/*.txt>) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

    while (<$fh>) {
        $count += /\Q$find\E/g;
    }

    close $fh;
}

print $count;
```

The `glob` denoted by `<$dir/*.txt>` will non-recursively get the names of all text files in the directory `$dir`.  If you want all files, change it to  `<$dir/*>`.  Each file is `open`ed and read, line-by-line.  The regex `/\Q$find\E/g` globally matches the contents of `$find` against each line.  The `\Q ... \E` notation escapes any meta-characters in the string you're looking for, else those characters may interfere with the matching.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a one liner in `bash`

```
grep "ObjectName " <filename> | wc -l
```

Comment: No i Need an Script an Perl Script Cos i have lots of things to start from there

Comment: @Bala_Tech then use system call :)